# Turn Based Game Match Data in iOS

Tags: ios, cocos2d, turn-based, game-center

Hi I’m working on turn based game development using turn based API from Apple’s GameKit framework. My game is 2 player strategy game.  Currently I’m facing the issue match data update on game play screen when the player complete their turn. I have more animation on game play, so the turn  data make impact both side.

and also we need reference or guidance for following questions:

1.when i get invite from the opponent player, the app will launch and authenticate on home screen but didn’t navigate to game play screen.

2.How the match data manage easily?

3.I have  3 primary leaderboard to play the game, Is this possible to update scoreboard for every turn?